# Access violation on pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

In this code, I am trying to convert a decimal number to binary. (Yes, I am aware that such a function exists -- I was trying to reinvent the wheel as an exercise.) Because I am using a function `toBinNum()` to convert the number, I wanted to pass an empty array by reference, then store my binary digits in the array, and upon returning to the `main()` function, I would have the array `binNum`. This does not happen; I pass the pointer, initialize it and store my binary digits, but then when I return to `main()` and attempt to access the pointer, it fails, issuing an `"Access violation on pointer"` error. I am assuming that the memory is being freed up, although I can't figure out why, given that the scope of the pointer is in `main()`, and the `new` keyword was used in `toBinNum()` when I created the array inside it. Why isn't this working, and how can I fix it?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void toBinNum(int, int*, int&);

int main(){
    int* binNum = nullptr; //binNum will hold the array of binary digits
    int binNumSize;
    toBinNum(100, binNum, binNumSize);

    int numOnes = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < binNumSize; j++){
        if (binNum[j] == 1) //ERROR.
            numOnes++;
        cout << binNum[j];
    }
    cout << numOnes;

    cin.get();
}

/*void toBinNum().
Converts decimal number to binary. 
Parameters: 
    binNum is an int pointer with value NULL, toBinNum() will use this pointer to store an int array of 0s and 1s it generates (each index will hold a binary value).
    binNumSize is an int, holds the length of the binNum array for use in other scopes
    decNum is an int, it is the decimal number that is to be converted to binary.
*/
void toBinNum(int decNum, int* binNum, int& binNumSize) {
    binNumSize = int(log2(decNum)) + 1; //How many digits will binNum be?
    binNum = new int[binNumSize];
    int factor = pow(2, binNumSize - 1); //What is the largest 2^n that we should start dividing decNum by?

    //Find 1s and 0s for binary array
    for (int j = 0; factor >= 1; j++){
        if (decNum / factor > 0){
            binNum[j] = 1; // 1 1 0 0 1
            decNum %= factor; //100   36   4   0
        }
        else
            binNum[j] = 0;
        factor /= 2;  // 64   32    16   8   4   2
    }

    //Output each index of binNum. Confirmation that this function works.
    for (int j = 0; j < binNumSize; j++)
        cout << binNum[j] << endl;

}
```

Comment: You may to allocate the memory binNum in the main before to use it inside the function that calculates the binary digit. Why don't you use an array of chars? ... To allocate binNum inside the function you have to modify the function prototype as void toBinNum(int decNum, int * &binNum, int& binNumSize) otherwise the pointer is passed by value and not by reference, passing the pointer by value, the function cannot change the contents of binNum and then, when the function terminates, binNum has the same value that It had before the function had been called!

Comment: To compute the number of bits it's better to use other kind of code, because in some case log2 may return a value different due to floating rounding! E.G.:  `len = 64;while( ! (value & (1ULL<< (len - 1)))  &&  len > 1) len--;`

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I don't understand -- when would `log2()` ever return a different value? Even at the extremes, where `log2()` evaluates to, say, 2.999, a casting to `int()` will still make it 2. Assuming `decNum` has a value of 7.9999, it should still make it an array of length `log2(7.999)+1` --> 2+1 --> 3, which will hold the number 7 as `111`. Can you give me an example of where there might be an issue? As many times as I've read the comment, I do not understand (although this is likely a failing on my part, being a beginner -- I didn't understand the `value & (1ULL<<` code, for example).

Comment: Try to use my code in the reply below uncommenting  the log2 function and then inserting -1 at the prompt  (-1 shall be converted in the max ULL, 64bit value) and you will discover because I said that! ... the result is 64 instead of 63 then `len` results to be 65!

Comment: Furthermore, using log, you cannot convert 0 because log2(0) is an error!

Comment: The code `(1ULL << bitpos)` (ULL = 64 bit) sets a  64 bit-value that has only the bit indicated by `bitpos` set, than if you make a logic and (`&`) between such a value and a value you obtain 1 only if that bit is set! You might use such a code also to count the number of bits which have 0 or 1 value in a number!

Comment: I've written "you obtain 1" ... is not true! You obtain 0 if the bit is not set and a value different from 0 if the bit is set in the value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the pointer by reference

```
void toBinNum(int, int* &, int&);
```

In C you can use one more indirection

```
void toBinNum(int, int**, int*);
```

The problem with your function declaration is that any parameter that is not passed by reference (though a reference is also a local variable of the function) is a local variable of the function that is destroyed after exiting the function. Any changes of the local variable do not influence on the original argument.

You can imagineg the function call the following way. Lets's assume that you have a function declared like

```
void f( int *p );
```

and you call it the following way

```
int main()
{
    int *q = nullptr;

    f( q );

    //...
```

then the function definition can be imagined like

```
void f( /* int *p */ )
{
    int *p = q;

    p = new int;

    //...
```

As you see the argument `q` was not changed. It is local variable `p` that got a new value.

Comment: I'm confused. By passing int*, I'm passing a pointer that was created in `main` and only modifying it's value in `toBinNum()`. Because the pointer exists in main, why wouldn't it and any `new` values it is assigned remain after the scope returns to `main`? In addition, why does making it a reference to an int* via `int* &` allow the `new` memory allocated later to stick around?

Comment: @Alex G  As I said a parameter is a local variable of the function that has block scope. It gets a copy of the value of the corresponding argument.  See my updated post.

Comment: Oh. I understand. That makes sense now, basically right now I'm just passing a pointer but I'm only passing it by value. I thought I was passing by reference but didn't realize that I'm not. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this reply isn't a proper answer to the question (I've replied in the comments above the question), but I think that is a nice solution to convert numbers in binary format. **However it show you the idea to allocate resources outside the function call** without using `**` or `&*`.

I use the code below to print out binary conversions of integer numbers. In such a code I use a function `iToBin()` to convert an integer number into an array of chars which may be printed or used whatever you want. This function uses also an optional parameter - `sym` - that may be used to specify which "symbols" are to be inserted into the array instead of the symbols '0' and '1'. The function `iToBin()` encodes the higher bit into the first element of the `buff` array then `buff[0]` is the higher bit of the converted number.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdint.h>

using namespace std;

char * iToBin(uint64_t n, char *buff, int len, const char *sym=(const char []){'0','1'});

char * iToBin(uint64_t n,char *buff,int len, const char *sym)
{
    uint64_t k=1;
    *(buff+ --len)=0;

    do {
        *(buff+ --len)=(n&k)?sym[1]:sym[0];
        k<<=1;
    } while(k && len);

    return buff;
}

int main(void) {
    uint64_t value;
    int len=0;
    char * buff;

    buff=new char[sizeof(value)*8+1];
    if (buff==NULL) {
       cout << "Not enough memory" << endl;
       return 1;
    }

    do  {
        cout << "Insert the value to convert: ";
        cin >> value;

        //len=(log2(value)+1); //number of digit
        //len++; // to insert the string0 terminator
        //It's better to use this to compute the number of bits!
        len=64;
        while(!(value & (1ULL<<(len-1))) && len>1) len--;
        len++; //to insert string 0 terminator

        iToBin(value,buff,len);

        int numOnes=0;

        for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++) {
            if (buff[i]=='1') {
                numOnes++;
            }
        }

        cout << buff << " contains " << numOnes << " 1" << endl;        

    } while(value!=0);

    delete buff;

    return 0;
}
```

You may use also different symbol to have different output, in the case below you'll have an output where the 1 digits will be '+' and the 0 digits will be '-'. (`iToBin()` may be used directly to print out the result because it returns the array pointer value)

```
    char sym[2];
    sym[0]='-';sym[1]='+';

    cout << iToBin(value,buff,len,sym) << endl;
```

You may use the code below to have a code where the bits are represented by the 0 and 1 numeric value:

```
sym[0]=0;sym[1]=1;
```

but the buffer result will not be useful as a C 0-terminated string!